# Changing the Line Style in an Interactive Data Display Multi-Chart in WPF with Visual C#

Tags: c#, wpf, plot, linegraph, dynamic-data-display

I've been through the forums for a few days, and I'm afraid I still haven't found an answer. So please excuse me if it's already somewhere else. And please tell me where you found it?

But I'm writing a GUI for my Master's thesis that needs to display scientific data on the biomass and catch rates of different species. Following suggestions in various forums/blogs, I'm using Interactive Data Display (previously D3). Unfortunately, I need to change the color to match the species, and the line type to match the management type. And I can't figure out the latter.

I followed [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/InteractiveDataDisplay.WPF/tree/master/samples/LineGraphSample) example but get my data from elsewhere in the programme.

I know D3.js lets you change the pen but C# apparently doesn't? Any help (including a different plotting package that does have the looked for functionality) to set the line-style to dashed would be appreciated.